# The Cramer-Rao lower bound of $e^{-(x-\theta)}\exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)})$

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference, variance

Let $f(x;\theta ) = e^{-(x_i-\theta)}exp(-e^{-x_i-\theta)})$

How do I find the Cramer-Rao lower bound?

the log likelihood is

$l(\theta;x)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n{[-(x_i-\theta )-e^{-(x_i-\theta )}]}$

and taking the derivative of the log likelihood gives:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}l(\theta;x)=n+\Sigma_{i=1}^n[e^{-(x_i-\theta)}]$

Taking the second derivative gives:

$\frac{\delta^2}{\delta\theta^2}l(\theta;x)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n{e^{-(x_i-\theta)}}$

And the expected value of this is:

$$E[\frac{\delta^2}{\delta\theta^2}l(\theta;x)]=n\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)}-2(x-\theta)) \ dx$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: the derivative $\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}l(\theta;x)=n+\Sigma_{i=1}^n[-1-e^{-(x-\theta)}]$ is not correct .. the $-1$ term shouldn't be there .. also your summation should be indexed by $i$ so $x_i$ instead of $x$

Comment: You are right. I have made the changes.

Comment: this is still wrong $\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}l(\theta;x)=n+\Sigma_{i=1}^n[-e^{-(x_i-\theta)}]$ .. should be $\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}l(\theta;x)=n+\Sigma_{i=1}^n[e^{-(x_i-\theta)}]$

Comment: changes made. So Am I on the right track in the end taking the integral? Are there any simplifications besides taking the integral of that form in the end?

Comment: yeah but the CRB is $I^{-1}(\theta)$ where $I(\theta) =- E[\frac{\delta^2}{\delta\theta^2}l(\theta;x)] $

Comment: other than that i think what you did is correct . 
Any ideas how to tackle the integration ?

Comment: It might help to notice that $e^{-X_1}$ is Exponential with mean $e^{-\theta}$.